# How to get a list containing every record from csv file that contain several strings on individual rows and are separated by new lines using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file that contains several rows. The issue is that there are some cells that have several records separated by new lines. I would like to have a new list or dataframe containing rows of individual records.

I have used a for loop to iterate through the CSV records and within the loop used splitlines() function to split the records that has more than one valued separated by newlies. This will give me a new list with sub-list within the list for the rows that have more than 1 value separated by newlines.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = 'LineItemsExport-20190805_2326_CDT.csv'
dfTemp = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# keeping only the column we are interested in
df= dfTemp['Modifiers']

# getting rip of nan values
dfCleaned = [x for x in df if str(x) != 'nan']

# splitting rows with more than one value
dfSplitNew = []
for i in range(len(dfCleaned)):
    dfSplitNew.append(dfCleaned[i].splitlines())

# creating dataframe to create an excel file with output values
dfPD = pd.DataFrame(dfSplitNew)
dfSplitNew.to_excel("outputList.xlsx")
```

To give you an idea the data I am having in the CSV is as follows:

```
Index   Modifier  
1       Beef    
2       Chicken  
        Pork  
        Sausage  
3       Beef
```

Chicken, Pork and Sausage are on the same cell on row 2 column 2 and they are separated by newlines. I would like my code to create two more rows to have pork and sausage on separate records.

With the code I have right now I am just getting a new list with sublist whenever there is more than one value on a row. I need a new row for every value inside the row that is separated by newline.

------------ UPDATE: SOLVED BELOW ------------

I could solve the problem creating a for loop to go row by row and an if statement to check where there were more than 1 value per row and in those cases I made use of 'extend' function to add all those values into a new list. Code below:

```
# importinng libraries
import pandas as pd
# loading the file
excel_file = 'LineItemsExport-20190805_2326_CDT.csv'
dfTemp = pd.read_csv(excel_file)

# keeping only the column we are interested in
df= dfTemp['Modifiers']

#getting rip of nans
dfCleaned = [x for x in df if str(x) != 'nan']

# splitting newline values into a new list
dfSplitNew = []
for i in range(len(dfCleaned)):
    dfSplitNew.append(dfCleaned[i].splitlines())
#print(dfSplitNew)

# checking row by row and extracting values for rows that has more than one value
dfnew = []
for index in range(len(dfSplitNew)):
    dftemp = dfSplitNew[index]
    if len(str(dftemp)) > 1:
        dfnew.extend(dftemp)
    else:
        dfnew.append(dftemp)

#making the list a dataframe to use pd to export data to xlsx
dfPD = pd.DataFrame(dfnew)
dfPD.to_excel("outputList.xlsx")
```

Comment: Could you show a sample of the csv file?

Comment: Sure, sample below

Col1    Col2    NumCol
Value 1 Value 2 123
This is a row with only one cell
This row is testing html entities   Te<br />st  45

Comment: As you see, the comments is not the right place, is not possible to format the text. Better to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57777538/edit) your post, so you can use the proper format.

Comment: Hi @Valentino thank you for trying to help. I am sorry I pasted the table info on the comment. I now edited the post and included an example of the table but have not find a good way to show tables here. I tried html and senseful but none of them worked properly. Anyways I used double spaces to create new lines and I think you can now have an idea of what I have. Please, let me know should you need any further explanation.

Comment: No, actually chicken, pork, sausage, and beef are 4 different items. Every row has to have only 1 item. Right now, there are rows (ie. row index 2) where there are three items (chicken, pork & sausage) separated by newline breaks. What I need is to take those items separated by line breaks and create new rows to store them separately.

Comment: Yes, I read better your question later. So the index marks the first row of the broken cell. That's useful to know

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `pandas`, I suggest to use `pandas` from the beginning. You can use the following approach,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+')
```

The above line reads the csv file with pandas, I assume separator is one or more whitespace, if not replace the value of 'sep' with the character separator.

```
nanpos = df['Modifier'].isna()
df['Modifier'] = np.where(nanpos, df['Index'], df['Modifier'])
df['Index'] = np.where(nanpos, np.nan, df['Index'])
df['Index'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Here the dataframe is manipulated a bit. Since some values in the last column are missing, they are filled by default with `nan`. Hence what is done here is:

1. Switch the column values where there is a `nan`, so that the modifier values is placed in the `'Modifier'` column and the `nan` values in the `'Index'` column.
2. `fillna` is used to replace the `nan` values with the previous index. If you print now `df` you'll see that it has become:

   ```
     Index Modifier
   0     1     Beef
   1     2  Chicken
   2     2     Pork
   3     2  Sausage
   4     3     Beef
   ```

Now I can use the index to join together the values using `groupby`:

```
ddf = df.groupby('Index').apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x['Modifier']))
```

`ddf` is:

```
Index
1                    Beef
2    Chicken Pork Sausage
3                    Beef
```

Comment: Valentino, thank you very much for your help. I think I did not explain myself well, I was not worried about 'nan' or missing values if that is the case I just need to remove them. I just want to extract the values inside column modifier that are contained in just one cell. Those values are inside the same row and are separated by line-breaks. There should be only one value per row and in some cases there were more than one. Hopefully, I could do that, I will update my question to show the code and the result. Thank you for your prompt response brother.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand the problem. Seems you have solved. In case, you can post your solution as an answer and accept it rather than add it in your question. That is the common way to do it, and people will know immediately that the question has found an answer